# Как в python вызвать возможность по типу "сохранить как"?

Tags: python, opencv, save, cv2

```py
import os
import pickle
import sys
import face_recognition
#from cv2 import cv2
import cv2



def take_creenshot_from_video():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # если 0 то камера, если нужно видео то указать имя видео в кавычках.
    count = 0

    if not os.path.exists("dataset_from_video"):
        os.mkdir("dataset_from_video")


    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
        multiplier = fps * 3
        #print(fps)

        if ret:
            frame_id = int(round(cap.get(1)))
            #print(frame_id)
            cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
            k = cv2.waitKey(20)

            #if frame_id % multiplier == 0: #тайминг в 3 секкунды (сам делает фото)
                #cv2.imwrite(f"dataset_from_video/{count}.jpg", frame)
                #print(f"Take a screenshot {count}")
                #count += 1

            if k == ord(" "): #по кнопке делается скрин
                cv2.imwrite(f"dataset_from_video/{count}_extra_scr.jpg", frame)
                print((f"Take an extra screenshot {count}"))
                count += 1
            elif k == ord("q"):#закрытие программы по кнопке
                print("Q pressed, closing the app")
                break


        else:
            print("[Error] Can't get the frame...")
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def main():
    #print(train_model_by_img("person_name"))
    take_creenshot_from_video()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: В смысле должен выйти диалог "Сохранить как..." с запросом имени файла куда сохранить или что? Так то можете и просто через `input` название файла запросить. Или вам нужно продвинутый диалог именно?

Comment: Не думаю, что у самого opencv есть такой диалог. Вы можете через tkinter его вызвать, например https://stackoverflow.com/a/42190297/5909792

Comment: @CrazyElf
Нужен диалог выбора папку куда я хочу это сохранить.

Comment: Ну тогда без какого-нибудь `GUI` не обойтись, да